# Best method for similarity searching on 10,000 data points with 8,000 features each in Python?

Tags: python, search, search-engine

As mentioned in the title I am attempting to search through 10,000 vectors with 8000 features each, all in Python. Currently I have the vectors saved in their own directories as pickled numpy arrays. The features were pulled from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.00449.pdf) deep neural network.

I am new to this space, but I have heard about M-Trees, R-Trees, inverted tables, and hashing. Is any one of them better for such a large number of features?

This implementation needs to be done quite rapidly and is just a prototype, so simplicity is valuable.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Facebook has a [new library](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1373769912645926/faiss-a-library-for-efficient-similarity-search/), but it's not wise to perform similarity search on such high dimensional spaces with a common metric like the Euclidean distance. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions

Comment: @Emre, yes. I saw their library however they mention on the wiki that the number of dimensions should be in the range of "a few 10s to 100s".

Comment: For good reason.

Comment: @Emre, why is using L2 distance not recommended for this number of dimension? Is that based on computation time, accuracy, or something else?

Comment: Based on the [concentration of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure). I linked to an explanation already.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main paths:

1. Load all vectors into memory. If you are able to load vectors into memory, then you might be able to search the space with "clever" brute force. One such method is found in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3828).
2. Keep vectors on disk. If you follow this path, then you have to index the vectors. You are basically building a search engine. Common open source search engines are: [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch)

It also depends on what kind of what kind of search is needed. A working definition of "close" vector is needed. The most common definitions of "close" vectors can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328714/how-to-efficiently-search-a-set-of-vectors-for-a-vector-which-is-the-closest-mat).

[Fais](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) is a new library for efficient similarity search of vectors. It is designed for many vectors (> 1,000,000) each being relatively small (10s to 100s  of dimensions). It may or may not scale to your problem. If it does not scale because of high dimensionality, you can reduce dimensionality with [Principal component analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction#Principal_component_analysis_.28PCA.29) or [t-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding).